# Selective file download permission with Apache and PHP

Tags: php, apache, file, download

I have a website with a file download option. However not everyone is allowed to download every file. For example if I log in as administrator I can download all files, but if I log in as a customer I can only download certain files.

Currently all these files are stored in a directory outside of the web root, so users can't download them manually. I made a PHP script to manage the downloading of files, but it's very buggy. I tried several things:

1:

```
echo file_get_contents($file);
```

2:

```
readfile($file);
```

3:

```
if (($handle = fopen($file, "rb")) !== false)
{
  while (!feof($handle))
  {
    echo fread($handle, 4096);
  }
  fclose($handle);
}
```

I found that all of these methods are very unreliable when testing with a 500MB file. The first and second both fail with all browsers and random percentages. Sometimes they already fail after a few megabytes, while other times they make it as far as 80%. But eventually they'll just stop downloading without any errors.

The 3rd method is most reliable. It downloads well in Firefox (albeit way too slow; about 700KB/s while it's from localhost and the readfile-method goes at 25MB/s when it works) and Chrome but in Internet Explorer it mostly fails. In IE it first gets stuck on "getting file information" without getting any "Open/Save" dialog. When I cancel that and try again I get an "Open/Save" dialog.

I searched the internet and I can't find any satisfying method that actually works well. Preferably I just want Apache to handle the file download since that always works perfectly without problems. But I don't want to put all files into a public directory since then everyone could download all files.

What are my options? Is there a best method?

Comment: to set file / mime header - `<? header('Content-type: application/pdf'); header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"'); // .. fread ?>`

Comment: If you've Apache's deflate module enabled, do not forget to turn it off for a download script. It caused me a few hours of headaches because Firefox didn't show a progress bar while downloading. To turn it off, add `SetEnv no-gzip` to a .htaccess file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Lekensteyn, I saw it used at another download script example so promptly checked if I had the deflate module enabled. I don't have it enabled.

Answer (score 2):

1) and 2) will break for big files because they fill the script's memory with the file's contents. The memory limit is usually something like 32 or 64 MB, and it's unwise to take any higher.

The 3rd method should work well because it doesn't fill the script's memory; however, remember to send the correct `content-type` and `content-length` headers.

There is an alternative to passing the file through PHP that I haven't worked with myself but seems to be working well, the [X-Sendfile](http://john.guen.in/past/2007/4/17/send_files_faster_with_xsendfile/) header.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was aware of the memory problems, so I increased the memory limit in my php.ini (however I can imagine PHP still has internal memory troubles with big files). I simply use filesize() for the Content-Length header (I'm aware it breaks at 2GB+ but the limit for my files is 500MB anyway). I'm using application/octet-stream as Content-Type. I'll check out what X-Sendfile does and see if it works better. :)

Comment: Memory is indeed one limitation - **execution time** might be another. Keep checking your php.ini file, if it works for 10Mb, it should be possible for 500 :)

Comment: Ah yes I forgot to mention the execution time. I added a line to the PHP script to set the execution time to infinite (since I'm not running in safe mode any way). Your note that if it works for 10MB it should work for 500MB is interesting, because my results differ. Files 1B - ~20MB work fine but larger files, like 200MB+, get increasingly unreliable.

Comment: I've been trying to get X-Sendfile to work and it was quite a hassle. I had a lot of problems with files not being inside of the root directory and it not understanding Windows file paths correctly, or something. It's a very elegant solution and I like it a lot! I'll use it for now, but I still want to get my script to work somehow without having to rely on a 3rd party Apache module that I have to install separately. :)

Comment: @pbean sadly, as far as I know, there is no easier way to combine PHP authentication and serving files than x-sendfile. Nginx is said to have the functionality built-in but I doubt whether you'll want to switch servers for this.

Comment: Switching servers isn't really an option, no. I now list the apache modules with apache_get_modules() and see if XSendFile is installed. If so, it uses that, otherwise it still uses my "manual" way. I still want to figure out why my "manual" way (just looping and "echo fread()"-ing) doesn't work reliably enough.

Comment: @pbean - if its failing reproducibly then you've already got the biggest problem solved! Try looking at the packet stream between client and server to see which end is terminating and whether its because the connection went quiet. BTW do have a look at the TCP window scaling between the 2 ends.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options, including to set the PHP headers, forcing download:

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="example.zip"'); 
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
```

http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/headers.htm

Or you could include an iFrame linked to the file in question...not particularly elegant however.

This is an interesting tutorial also:

http://w-shadow.com/blog/2007/08/12/how-to-force-file-download-with-php/

Comment: I already use the Content-Type and Content-Disposition headers (obviously), but I'll add the Content-Transfer-Encoding and see how that turns out.

Comment: Sure- I've ammended with another article which may be of interest